# Automapper: How do I automatically map 40 properties using the Culture defined on the object?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a gigantic DTO that needs mapping, and I've been looking for a way to map all of the decimal properties to string, based on the language contained within the object. All the decimal to string mappings are mapped in an identical fashion.

```cs
public class MyEntity
{    
    public int CustomerLanguage { get; set; } // used to determine how to map all the Cost properties

    public decimal Cost1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost2 { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost3 { get; set; }
//..
    public decimal Cost40 { get; set; }

    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProperty2 { get; set; }
//.. more properties
}


public class MyDto
{
    public string Cost1 { get; set; }
    public string Cost2 { get; set; }
    public string Cost3 { get; set; }
//..
    public string Cost40 { get; set; }

    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProperty2 { get; set; }
//.. more properties
}
```

The following code works, but is silly, and I think it defeats the purpose of AutoMapper:

```cs
public class LangResolver : IMemberValueResolver<MyEntity, MyDto, decimal, string> {
    public string Resolve(MyEntity source, MyDto destination, decimal sourceMember, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var cost = decimal.Round(sourceMember, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        return source.CustomerLanguage == 2
            ? $"{cost.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CA"))}$"
            : $"${cost.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-CA"))}";
    }
}
```

```cs
        CreateMap<MyEntity, MyDto>()
            .ForMember(m => m.Cost1, n => n.MapFrom<LangResolver, decimal>(s => s.Cost1))
            .ForMember(m => m.Cost2, n => n.MapFrom<LangResolver, decimal>(s => s.Cost2))
            .ForMember(m => m.Cost3, n => n.MapFrom<LangResolver, decimal>(s => s.Cost3))
//...
            .ForMember(m => m.Cost38, n => n.MapFrom<LangResolver, decimal>(s => s.Cost38))
            .ForMember(m => m.Cost39, n => n.MapFrom<LangResolver, decimal>(s => s.Cost39))
            .ForMember(m => m.Cost40, n => n.MapFrom<LangResolver, decimal>(s => s.Cost40))
```

My question is if any out there knows a more automatic way of resolving this? Using Automapper 11.0.1

I tried playing around with nested configurations, passing in conditions like below, and I tried using .ForAllMembers, but the amount of exposed data is limited.

```cs
var data = _mapper.Map<MyDto>(someEntity,
    s => email.CustomerLanguage == 2 ? new FrenchResolver() : new EnglishResolver()));
```

I have a working solution already, but I was hoping to get someone with some Automapper insight. Thanks

EDIT: Added a sample Type Converter:

```
CreateMap<decimal, string>().ConvertUsing((@decimal, @string, resolutionContext) =>

    // resolutionContext does not expose the object

    languageType == 2 // there is no such thing
    ? $"{@decimal.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CA"))}$"
    : $"${@decimal.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-CA"))}";
);
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html

Comment: I already added a type converter before, and I could either map to either "$XX.YY" or "XX,YY$" but not both.

At that point, I only have access to decimal and string, not the entity/dto pair, and the ResolutionContext contains only the mappings.

Comment: You can pass the language in the context.

Comment: Well how about that. That works beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: [AutoMapper Usage Guidelines](https://www.jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/) - from Jimmy Bogard, the author of AutoMapper. DO NOT use AutoMapper except in cases where the destination type is a flattened subset of properties of the source type

AutoMapper is designed for projecting a complex model into a simple one. It can be configured to map complex scenarios, but this results in more confusing code than just assigning properties directly. If your configuration is complex, don't use this tool

Comment: Yes, but the code above is the problem and the solution is a converter.

Answer (score 1):

As Lucian suggested, I added the language to the context

```cs
var data = _mapper.Map<MyDto>(someEntity, opt => opt.Items["Language"] = customerLanguage);
```

and retrieved the property from the context inside the type converter

```cs
CreateMap<decimal, string>().ConvertUsing((@decimal, @string, resolutionContext) =>
{
    // obviously make your code more robust than this
    var customerLanguage = (int)resolutionContext.Items["Language"];
    return customerLanguage == 2
        ? $"{@decimal.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CA"))}$"
        : $"${@decimal.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-CA"))}";
});
```